# Reinitialize Service when authenticating

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm creating an Angular application which uses a WebSocket connection to communicate with a backend server. When logging in the server sends several packages of information which are processed by different services, like this:

```
constructor(private socketService: SocketService, private authService: AuthService) {
  this.obs$ = this.socketService.get().pipe(filter(data => data[SocketService.CONTROLLER] === 'account'));
  this.details$ = this.obs$.pipe(
    filter(data => data[SocketService.ACTION] === 'details'),
    map(data => data[SocketService.PAYLOAD]),
    takeUntil(this.authService.logout),
    shareReplay({bufferSize: 1, refCount: true}));
}
```

This works fine when logging in for the first time - so when the service is created, but when logging out and in again the service constructor is not triggered again and it seems that the Observable `details$` does not emit any value. When the `refCount` is removed the details of the first account I login with is shown even when loggin in with a different account.

This works for first login in a component but not on a second one.

```
this.accountService.getDetails().subscribe(d => console.log(d));
```

The service is provided by a module which is imported in a lazy loaded module. What's the best practice to solve this? What I thought of is to create an init method for every service which is called on login, but that seems pretty unintuitive and kinda wrong. I need the service to receive the data even if it's currently not used by any component.

Comment: you can use authService's observable in conjugation with socketservice via `combinelatest`

Comment: cant u just remove takeUntil?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov the observable then still does not emit a value

Comment: `details$ emits only an empty value` - what's that empty value?(e.g `null`, `undefined`); also, the expected behavior is that when you log in again, you should receive the latest emitted value, right?

Comment: @AndreiGătej Updated the text, the observable does not emit any value at all. On login the observable should be populated with a new value, as the backend sends that value only once on login it should be cached in the service for several components to access.

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz?

Comment: If  `details$` remains without subscriber **before** `this.authService.logout` emits, then when a new subscriber is created(e.g on log in), the source should be re-subscribed.

Comment: @AndreiGătej Created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ge8xsw). I think I will have to run the whole observable pipe when logging in, not in the service constructor - anything else actually does not seem make any sense. Issue then is that the `shareReplay` keeps the data cached even when the `takeUntil` emits. Using `refCount: true` removes the data even while still logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Case 1

```js
takeUntil(this.authService.logout),
shareReplay({bufferSize: 1, refCount: false})
```

Navigating between `/other` and `/details`  - same results because `refCount: false` won't cause the `ReplaySubject` in use to be destroyed so the source won't be re-subscribed when new subscribers will register and the `ReplaySubject` will stay intact

> the shareReplay keeps the data cached even when the takeUntil emits.

that is because the `takeUntil`'s notifier will emit **before** the component is destroyed(i.e when the subscriber will deregister). Then, `takeUntil` will emit a `complete` notification, which means that the `ReplaySubject` will `complete` as well:

```js
complete() {
  subscription = undefined;
  subject!.complete();
},
```

When a `ReplaySubject` receives a new subscriber **after** it has completed, [these lines](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/3f3c614d8b86c68d271a1db995ff11c61842e757/src/internal/ReplaySubject.ts#L114-L116) will be reached, so the new subscriber will receive all the cached values and a `complete` notification.

And because the `shareReplay`'s source has completed, it can't receive any other values, because the `Subscriber` which listens for notification [has completed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/3f3c614d8b86c68d271a1db995ff11c61842e757/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L123-L128), thus it became `stopped`:

```js
complete(): void {
  if (!this.isStopped) {
    this.isStopped = true;
    this._complete();
  }
}
```

---

#### Case 2

```js
takeUntil(this.authService.logout),
shareReplay({bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
```

Navigating between `/other` and `/details`  - only the first time the data is displayed as the source is the `SocketService`'s `Subject` instance; so when the `Subject` instance is subscribed, the subscriber will be added to a list of subscribers, so that when a the `Subject` emits a value, all the registered subscribers will receive it

When logging out:

```js
onLogout() {
  this.authService.doLogout();
  this.router.navigate(['/'])
}
```

`takeUntil` will emit before the subscriber is removed from the `ReplaySubject`'s list of subscribers(that is, when the comp is destroyed, e.g `this.router.navigate(['/'])`).

`takeUntil` will then emit a `complete` notification and [here's](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/shareReplay.ts#L167-L170) what will happen:

```js
complete() {
  subscription = undefined;
  subject!.complete();
},
```

and then `this.router.navigate(['/'])` will cause the component to be destroyed and because you're also using the async pipe, it will unsubscribe from the `ReplaySubject` used by `shareReplay`, so these lines will be reached:

```js
if (subscription && useRefCount && refCount === 0) {
  subscription.unsubscribe();
  subscription = undefined;
  subject = undefined;
}
```

The expression will be `false`, as `subscription` is already undefined(from the `complete` callback).

---

#### A possible solution

#### auth.service.ts

I thought it may be useful to modify this service a bit, in order to be able to properly distinguish between logged in states(`true` or `false`).

```js
loggedIn = new Subject<boolean>();


doLogin() {
  this.loggedIn.next(true);
}

doLogout() {
  this.loggedIn.next(false);
}
```

#### account.service.ts

```js
this.details$ = this.obs$.pipe(
  filter(data => data[SocketService.ACTION] === "details"),
  map(data => data[SocketService.PAYLOAD]),

  startWith(null),

  takeUntil(this.authService.loggedIn.pipe(filter(v => v === false))),

  repeatWhen(
    completeSbj => completeSbj.pipe(
      switchMapTo(this.authService.loggedIn.pipe(filter(v => v === true), take(1))),
    )
  ),

  shareReplay({bufferSize: 1, refCount: false })
);
```

Let's go through each relevant block of code.

As you can see, we kept `shareReplay({bufferSize: 1, refCount: false })`, because we don't want the `ReplaySubject` to be destroyed when it has no subscriber, thus we don't want to re-subscribe to the source.

With this, you can navigate through routes as long as you wish, but the data will be the same for the user.

`takeUntil(this.authService.loggedIn.pipe(filter(v => v === false))),` we want to emit a complete notification when the user logs out.

```js
repeatWhen(
  completeSbj => completeSbj.pipe(
    switchMapTo(this.authService.loggedIn.pipe(filter(v => v === true), take(1))),
  )
),
```

will allow us to re-subscribe to the source when the user logs in again, after it had logged out. So, we will get a new value(as seen by the `SocketService`'s `counter` variable) every time a user logs in.

Lastly, `startWith(null),` is particularly useful when the user logs in, then logs out and then logs in again. Without this operator, on the second log in, the user would see the previous data(e.g `Awesome Data 1`). But when using this, since the re-subscription is done when the user logs in again(due to `this.authService.loggedIn.pipe(filter(v => v === true), take(1))`), we would first get `null` as a value, until the `SocketService` provides the data.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nice-share-replay-case?file=src%2Fapp%2Faccount.service.ts).

Comment: Definitly one up for the information, thanks a lot. I will try it out asap.

Comment: Does not want to work in my application yet, haven't quite figured out why but as it works in stackblitz - even with me tinkering a bit more there - I will accept the awnser.

Comment: Hey, one more question: when I subscribe to `details$` for example do I have to explicitly unsubscribe? Because it seems that a `complete` or `finalize` is never reached/triggered when using `repeatWhen` even when `takeUntil` is triggered

Comment: Hello! I think you’ll have to add takeUntil after repeatWhen. Where more concisely, it say it depends. If you want a subscriber to be removed from ReplSbj’s subscribers list, then you can add it after shareReplay. If you add it before shareReplay, when that notifier emits, the source will be unsubscribed and shareReplay will send a complete notification to each registered subscriber.